# Update a GitHub project wiki through the GitHub API

Tags: github-api

Is there a way a developer can automatically upload [Doxygen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doxygen) documentation for his project hosted on [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub) through their API?

I didn't find anything on [develop.github.com](http://develop.github.com) related to this. It would be nice if one could just [SCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_copy) the files or something.

Answer (score 18):

It's now possible to check out the wiki as a separate Git repository. You could clone the repository, add the pages to it, and push it. You can clone the repository from this URL:

```
git@github.com:user/project.wiki.git
```

Answer (score 7):

There is no way, at this time, to access the GitHub wiki via the API. However, there is a much better solution already built into GitHub. Since Doxygen outputs static HTML pages, you can push them to the gh-pages branch of your project and access them at *username*.github.com/*projectname*

For more information, http://pages.github.com/.

Comment: I tried that, the problem for me is that now my git repository takes forever to clone, since git clone by default grabs all branches...

Comment: try `git clone --depth=1 git@github.com:foo/blah.git`